# Setting constant is not working programmatically. What can I be missing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, constraints

I have a image view with following constraints

height constraint = 250,
width constraint = 250,
leadingSpace constraint = 159 (on iPhone long screen) 
and 
topSpace constraint = 10

View is in landscape mode.

attached the leading space constraint in .h via the following code

```
IBOutlet (retain, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *leadingSpaceConstraint;
```

Now, when I run the following code in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, the constraint doesn't update

```
self.leadingSpaceConstraint.constant = 100; //new value;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; //I also tried the iboutlet for the imageView and running this line on it, but no updates.
```

How to update? What am I missing?

Comment: You've def wired up the right constraint to the outlet?

Comment: A similar code works for me. Are you sure there are no other constraints that conflict with what you're setting?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, I wired up the constraint properly. It shows a dot in the circle once its wired up.

Comment: @Ilya : Yes, there are no other constraints in conflict. I have manually attached the constraints. all constraints are in user control setting. :) Still its not working for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to put autolayout code in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: how can I do that for a view controller's view ?